# multiple column menu in iPhone

Tags: iphone, menu

I want to create a menu like below for my iPhone app. Is it possible?
First, only the main items will display. and when we clicking on a main item its sub items will show in two columns.

[image: menu]

Comment: Have a look at this [git](https://github.com/vicpenap/VPPDropDown).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is using a customized `UITableView` with sections.

- Each header of each section will correspond to your "Main Item X". You can use a custom view for your headers thanks to the `UITableViewDelegate` methods, so you can provide a `UIView` containing a `UILabel` and the image of your ">" or "v", and a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to handle the tap that will open of close the submenus
- Each section will contain either 0 (if the menu is closed) or N items (if it is open)
- Each cell of your tableView, that will correspond to a row, will contain two labels (or buttons), one for the item on the left and one for the item on the right.
- When the `UITagGestureRecognizer` of a section is tapped, you can toggle a `BOOL` that tells if the section is "open" or "closed" and then call `reloadData`  on your UITableView to show or hide the corresponding cells

The rest is basic table view programming so you can implement the table view as you usually do (see the "[Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)" in the Apple doc for more details).

Comment: It is simple just add two controls per row that way there is two columns in table view :)

Comment: If you want two columns, simply use custom tableviewcells that have two labels, one on the left and one on the right, as explained in my 3rd bullet point. (This is also explained in the "Table View Programming Guide" quoted in my answer, especially [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18))

Comment: Thanks AliSoftware. I will try... :)